# Multiple selector of elements selected via tree traversal

Tags: javascript, jquery, tree-traversal

```
$('.myclass').parent().prev().prev();
$('.myclass').parent().prev();
$('.myclass');
$('.myclass').parent().next();
$('.myclass').parent().next().next();
```

How to select all this elements in only one line via jQuery ?

I thought of this solution, but hope that there is something better :

```
$('.myclass').parent().prev().prev().addClass('select_me');
$('.myclass').parent().prev().addClass('select_me');
$('.myclass').addClass('select_me');
$('.myclass').parent().next().addClass('select_me');
$('.myclass').parent().next().next().addClass('select_me');

$('.select_me').fadeOut(); // I select all the previous elements in only 1 line.
```

Comment: please share the html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using `filter()` and `index()`

<strike>**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/Ba4fz/1/)**</strike>

```
idx = $('.myclass').parent().index();
$('.myclass').parent().siblings().addBack().filter(function(){    
    return  $(this).index() > idx -3 && $(this).index() < idx + 3;
}).addClass('select_me');
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/Ba4fz/2/)**

```
$('.myclass').each(function(){    
    currentObject = $(this);
    parent = $(this).parent();
    $(this).parent().siblings().filter(function(){
      return  $(this).index() > parent.index() -3 && $(this).index() < parent.index() + 3;
    }).add(currentObject).addClass('select_me');
});
```

Comment: great sir :) you defeated Arun P also :)

Comment: It's probably just as wrong as my solution, given the problem. +1

Comment: @Adi in the example he selects `.myclass` and you are selecting the parent of `.myclass`. Can't say if it is the same without the css/html

Comment: You are right, I missed that bit, I think this one gives the output he wants.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
$.merge($('.myclass'), $('.myclass').parent().siblings()).fadeOut();
```